# How can I fix my USB keyboard that keeps on chattering whenever I plugged in my laptop to its charger?

Tags: usb, laptop, keyboard, charging

I recently bought a USB keyboard and I am not having any problems with it unless I put my laptop on charging, it starts to **chatter** *(single key press results in multiple registered inputs)*. My laptop keyboard is completely fine though, whether it is charging or not.

I was wondering if it has something to do with my laptop charger since the one that I am using was only a universal charger (not the original laptop charger). I already did some changes in my keyboard properties such as the 'repeat delay' from short to long but it did not solve the problem.

I would really appreciate it if someone will help me figure this out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet it's the [rectifier](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/diode/diode_5.html) in the cheap PSU, being only half wave. Might fix if you earth it properly… or not, if it's not earthable.

Solution, really, would be a good PSU.